# ASP.Net LinkButton CSS Adapter

Tags: css, asp.net-2.0

Does anyone know of a CSS Adapter for the LinkButton control for ASP.Net 2?

**Update:**

We are trying to use CSS Buttons. We are using this approach: http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html For that we need to render the  tags which the link button doesn't do.

**Possible Solution using Adapter**

We created an adapter for the linkbutton. Then changed the RenderContents as follows:

```
  protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {

    LinkButton linkButton = this.Control;

    linkButton.Text = String.Concat("<span>", linkButton.Text, "</span>");

    base.Render(writer);
  }
```

This seems to work and requires minimum effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Solution using Adapter

We created an adapter for the linkbutton. Then changed the RenderContents as follows:

```
  protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {

    LinkButton linkButton = this.Control;

    linkButton.Text = String.Concat("<span>", linkButton.Text, "</span>");

    base.Render(writer);
  }
```

This seems to work and requires minimum effort.

Answer (score 1):

[Create a **Web Control**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx) which would inherit from [`LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) and only **override** the `RenderContents` method.

It's pretty straightforward and you shouldn't have to duplicate any code or re-implement any features. Of course it's helpful to use .NET Framework source to take a look at the original implementation.

Comment: problem with this approach is it requires to change all references in project for new control, but thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the output from the LinkButton control could be more CSS friendly.. it is a pure HTML Anchor.

Comment: I need to change the control rendering slightly.

Comment: I don't know it what way, you could just make you're own CSS adapter it shouldn't be difficult for such an easy control.. I can't really imagine in what way you would need to change the anchor rendering, if you explain your goal someone might be able to provide a pure CSS solution.

Comment: We are trying to use CSS Buttons. We are using this approach:

http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html

For that we need to render the <span> tags which the link button doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this with a user control or custom control to render out

```
<a...><span>[text]</span></a>
```

OR - you could use jQuery to find all anchors (maybe with a given class) and insert the span for you.

Comment: The problem with a user control / custom control is that we only want to override the rendering, not the functionality. WIth a user control / custom control we would have to recreate all the methods/properties and then delegate to the base control